# Get Complete Binance Futures Order Book with BinanceSocketManager

Tags: python, websocket

i'm new with Websoclets i really didnt understand de Python Doc and python-binance library doc so, im searching about. How to get complete order book from binance futures.
Binance doc says to open a stream..i think the code below does it as i understand

```
import asyncio

from binance import AsyncClient
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager


async def task_depth_socket(socket: BinanceSocketManager, ticker: str):
    print("Entrando a depth socket")
    depth_socket = socket.depth_socket(symbol = ticker)
    async with depth_socket as ds:
        while True:
            res = await ds.recv()
            print(res)


async def main():
   
    try:
   
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    socket = BinanceSocketManager(client)

    symbols = ["MANAUSDT"]
    tasks = []

    for s in symbols:
        tasks.append(task_depth_socket(socket, s))
        #tasks.append(task_trade_socket(socket, s))
    # asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

except KeyboardInterrupt as kbe:

    print('Programa terminado por interrupción manual')

finally:
    await AsyncClient.close_connection()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Then ti says to get a sanpshot from the API...i think it comes with this:

```
client = Client(api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret)
        order_book = client.futures_order_book(symbol=symbol, limit=1000)
        return order_book
```

But finally, it says to do the next steps and i dond understand how to mange that cause i dont understand what it is doing

- Drop any event where u is < lastUpdateId in the snapshot.
- The first processed event should have U <= lastUpdateId AND u >= lastUpdateId
- While listening to the stream, each new event's pu should be equal to the previous event's u, otherwise initialize the process from step 3.
- The data in each event is the absolute quantity for a price level.
- If the quantity is 0, remove the price level.
- Receiving an event that removes a price level that is not in your local order book can happen and is normal.

Can anyone explains waht am i sipose to do ? im lost
I hace my bot runnig without websocket ans using the API to get de 1000 data from it but, unitl now no problems but a partner just got ip banned for too many requests and i want to solve that
Thanks